# "To this effect"

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "to this effect" in the following sentence mean? (This sentence is in a reply of an application).

> However, if you are not successful, we will inform you to this effect.

Does this mean, if I failed I will still get informed(by a mail or phone-call) or if I failed, I will have no idea that I have failed already?

Comment: It means: if you fail, then they will inform you that you fail.

Comment: @GEdgar hi, i searched the internet for definition, it seems that "to that effect", "to the effect" has a defined meaning, but not "to this effect". A friend told me that it means: "in this sense", would you agree with this meaning?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how it could mean the latter. Could you explain your reasoning? "We will inform you X" can only mean "we will not inform you" if the X somehow amounts to "not", and I'm not quite sure how "to this effect" can leave such an impression on you.

Comment: @RegDwightΒВBẞ8 Hi, sorry, English is not my first language, so maybe I am not aware of this. I am asking because it's been quite some time since my applcation, and I haven't received any interview message nor rejection letter. SO i was wondering if they won't even inform me when I fail. (Like a double check.) :)

Comment: In this example: "this effect" is "you are not successful".  So "you are not successful" is what you will be informed of (if in fact you are not successful).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, "to this effect" is a specific instance of "to the effect" where "this" refers to the demonstrated meaning in the sentence.

Really, the phrase could be replaced with "thus" - ie "we will inform you thus", even more plainly, "we will inform you *that you were not successful*"

Answer (score 4):

I think OP's example is someone's misguided idea of "formal" writing style. Google Books reports [a couple](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22inform+you+to+this+effect%22) of written instances. but it just looks stilted and clumsy to me. The addition of *to this effect* conveys nothing at all here, since the statement already says you'll be informed if you're unsuccessful.

The standard formal usage ["**to this effect** we will [do sth]"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22elbow%20room%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22to%20this%20effect%20we%20will%22&hl=en&tbo=1&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1900,cd_max:1999&tbm=bks&source=lnt&sa=X&ei=1diaT8ToCoqo8APjjYmxCQ&ved=0CBoQpwUoAg&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=2f7879b441b121c8&biw=1237&bih=902) means *in order to effect (achieve) this*.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistakening , they meant with this result we will inform you.