# Correct usage of "to this effect"

Tags: phrases

Is this a correct usage of "to this effect"?

> I plan on coming to your soccer game on Sunday. Unfortunately, I cannot make any guarantees to this effect.

Comment: Related http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65928/to-this-effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s grammatical, but *to this effect* is far too formal an expression to use in that context. What you would say is something like *I can’t make any promises.*